# How to hide the menu in the second window in Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I’m making a small test application using Electron, below is the code.

When you click on the `about` in menu, a new window appears. How can I make the menu buttons disappear only in this window? Although this should not happen in the main window.

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
const globalElectron = require('electron');

let win;
let about;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html').then(r => r);
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
    win.on('closed', () => win = null);
}

function openAboutWindow()
{
    if (about) {
        about.focus();
        return
    }

    about = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 185,
        resizable: false,
        width: 270
    });

    about.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/about.html').then(r => r);
    about.on('closed', () => about = null);
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    createWindow();

    const template = [
        {
            label: 'Info',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'GitHub',
                    click: () => {
                        globalElectron.shell.openExternal('https://github.com/').then(r => r);
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            label: 'About',
            click: () => {
                openAboutWindow();
            }
        }
    ];

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate(template));
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    app.quit();
});
```

I’m just starting to study this, so I apologize for the possible poor quality of the code structure. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the menu on a specific window, you will have to call `.setMenu(null)` on it.

```js
function openAboutWindow()
{
    if (about) {
        about.focus();
        return
    }

    about = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 185,
        resizable: false,
        width: 270
    });

    about.setMenu(null); // here!
    about.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/about.html').then(r => r);
    about.on('closed', () => about = null);
}
```

(There are [some issues](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16521) with this function on some versions of Electron, I can confirm it works well on 7.1.11.)

Comment: Thank you for what you need!